# Double integral with two parameters $\int_{x_1=1}^{x_2=2}\int_{y_1=0}^{y_2=x}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\,dx\,dy$

Tags: definite-integrals, partial-derivative

Given the following integral:
$$\int_{y_1=0}^{y_2=x}\,dy\int_{x_1=1}^{x_2=2}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\,dx$$

I thought of using $u$-substitution:

$$\begin{align}
u &= \frac{y}{x} \\
w &= \arctan(u) \\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} &= -\frac{x}{y^2 \cdot (1 + u^2)} \\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} &= \frac{1}{y \cdot (1 + u^2)} 
\end{align}$$

But then... how do I use the partial derivatives for integration?

Comment: For the inner integral: $\int arctan(\frac{y}{x})dx$, use integration by parts.

Comment: Also, are the limits of integration in the correct order?

Comment: @mathamphetamines Probably not, I'll reverse the order... I'm the one who extracted the limits of integrations from the data of the question, so it's probably not in the right order.

Comment: @mathamphetamines: Using Integration by parts - how do I treat the parameters $x$ and $y$? for example when calculating the derivative of $\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$.

Comment: Since you're only integrating with respect to x first, you can treat y as a constant.  Let $ u = arctan\frac{y}{x}$ and let dv = dx

Comment: Are you expecting the double integral to evaluate to a function of $x$ or a constant? If the outer integral is $\int_{y = 0}^{y = x}$, then you'll end up with a function of $x$ as the result.

Comment: @mathamphetamines: Does treating `y` as a constant is valid although that `y` depends on `x`? (`y` is a function of `x`)

Comment: in this case you're working in 3 dimensions, so we usually write z = f(x,y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int \arctan(\frac{y}{x})\;dx, \;\text{ Let } u=\arctan\frac{y}{x}\; \Rightarrow \;
du = \frac{1}{(\frac{y}{x})^2+1}\cdot \frac{-y}{x^2}dx \; \Rightarrow \; du = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx \\  \text{and let } dv=dx \; \Rightarrow \; v=x \\ \text{Therefore} \\ \int u \;dv = uv \; - \; \int v\;du \;\; \Rightarrow \; \; \int \arctan\frac{y}{x}dx = \; x\cdot \arctan\frac{y}{x} \; + \; \int \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}dx
$$

To solve 
$$
\int \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}dx
$$
we can let $w = x^2+y^2$, where $\frac{1}{2}dw = x\;dx$

Which gives us
$$
\int \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}dx \; = \; \frac{1}{2}y\int\frac{1}{w}dw \; = \frac{1}{2}y\cdot \ln|w| \; = \frac{1}{2}\cdot y \cdot \ln|x^2+y^2|
$$

giving us the final result of
$$
\int \arctan\frac{y}{x}dx = x\cdot \arctan\frac{y}{x} \; + \; \frac{1}{2} \cdot y \cdot \ln|x^2+y^2|+C
$$

Comment: I've corrected my dumb mistakes, looks good now.

Comment: Your MathJax technique could use some work.  Please look at my edits. In particular "a\arctan b" yields $a\arctan b$ with proper spacing between $\arctan$ and $a$ and $b$ (and also it's not italicized).  Similarly with \ln.  And \text{} is useful. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Does this solution valid for when `z = f(x,y)`? After that we finish with the integration of `dx`, do we proceed with the integration of `dy` in a similar fashion?